# Seamless writing of uncompressed output when using the Rust gzp crate

Tags: rust, compression

I am using the Rust crate `gzp` to allow for multi-threaded compression of output data. I have run into one limitation with the interface. In my current application, I would like to optionally generate uncompressed output. This is especially true if the output is going to be written to `stdout`. However, with the current `gzp` interface this is challenging since a `ParCompress` object must call `finish()` before going out of scope.

I believe the typical solution for this would be something similar to:

```
let mut writer: Box<dyn Write + Send> = if compress {
    Box::new(
        ParCompressBuilder::new()
            .num_threads(processes)?
            .from_writer(out_file),
    )
} else {
    Box::new(BufWriter::with_capacity(1024 * 1024, out_file))
};
```

However, this doesn't work since one can't call `finish()` on `writer`. Is there a pattern I can use to allow for seamlessly writing data with a `ParCompress` or `BufWriter` writer depending on the state of my `compress` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lazy solution would be to go with the `either` crate:

```rust
let mut writer = if compress {
    Either::Right(
        ParCompressBuilder::new()
            .num_threads(processes)?
            .from_writer(out_file),
    )
} else {
    Either::Left(BufWriter::with_capacity(1024 * 1024, out_file))
};
writer.write(…)?; // Conveniently, Either implements Write if both Left and Right implement it
if let Either::Right(gzp) = writer {
    gzp.finish()?;
}
```

A bit more wordy, but more nicely encapsulating would be to define your own enum:

```rust
enum MaybeGzp<T: Write> {
    Gzp(ParCompress<Gzip>),
    Plain(BufWriter<T>),
}

impl<T: Write + Send + 'static> MaybeGzp<T> {
    pub fn new(file: T, compress: Option<usize>) -> Self {
        match compress {
            Some(processes) => MaybeGzp::Gzp(
                ParCompressBuilder::new()
                    .num_threads(processes)
                    .expect("Insane thread count")
                    .from_writer(file),
            ),
            None => MaybeGzp::Plain(BufWriter::with_capacity(1024 * 1024, file)),
        }
    }

    pub fn finish(self) -> anyhow::Result<()> /* lazy error handling */ {
        Ok(match self {
            MaybeGzp::Gzp(mut gzp) => gzp.finish()?,
            MaybeGzp::Plain(mut bw) => bw.flush()?,
            // Could also just do nothing in the Plain case,
            // but BufWriter's Drop ignores errors on Drop, so better catch it here
        })
    }
}
```

which you can then trivially implement write on:

```rust
impl<T: Write> MaybeGzp<T> {
    fn as_write(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
        match self {
            MaybeGzp::Gzp(gzp) => gzp,
            MaybeGzp::Plain(plain) => plain,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Write> Write for MaybeGzp<T> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.as_write().write(buf)
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.as_write().flush()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f19d88d4c12e6ab8a07cdcb6f145a9d5)

Comment: Thanks Caesar. I much appreciate the thorough response. The `either` crate is interesting, but your full solution gives me a lot to explore in terms of better using enums in Rust. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `ParCompress` with a newtype that has a destructor that calls `finish()`. It is a little old `gzp` doesn't do that itself.

Comment: `finnish()` is fallible, so doing that in a destructor is a bad idea. I'll post an alternative answer.

Comment: Hm, the [stdlib](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.72.0/src/std/io/buffered/bufwriter.rs.html#670-675) doesn't seem to think it's a bad idea. :/